# How to add anchor symbol

Tags: css, angularjs, anchor

I want to add an anchor symbol to my url when mouse hover in angular. Here is my code,

```
<a ng-click="download(File)"><img src="images/filePic.png"/>{{filename}}</a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this maybe

> ⚓ {{filename}}

```
<a ng-click="download(File)">&#9875; <img src="images/filePic.png"/>{{filename}}</a>
```

---

*Update using CSS hover*

```css
a:hover:after {
  content: ' \2693'
}
```

```html
<a ng-click="download(File)"><img src="http://placehold.it/15x15"/> some filename</a>
```

---

*Update 2 using CSS hover cursor*

```css
a:hover {
  cursor: url('https://onedrive.live.com/download?resid=EC849DFEDB797EB9!1066&authkey=!AEmDTZM6b8_Ies0&ithint=file%2ccur'),auto;
}
```

```html
<a ng-click="download(File)"><img src="http://placehold.it/15x15"/> some filename</a>

<br><br>
Note there is a small delay (first time hovering) from OneDrive before the anchor shows
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I mean, when mouse hover stack overflow Ask question, anchor symbol is coming like wise I want to add to my link.

Comment: Cant I change my mouse cursor symbol when mouse hover to my url ?